# Dell docking station D3100 with MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, dock

I am trying to setup 3 monitors with my MacBook Pro (Late 2013). I was wondering if anybody has tried this docking station with mac.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this worked for my MacBook Pro which is the Late 2013 model. You need to go to the DisplayLink website and download the driver for your Mac, the driver is called "DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Mac OS X." Then reboot your Mac and then plug in the Dell D3100.

Comment: doesn't work for me.

Comment: Downloaded from : https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos, You may need to enable the _app driver to take control your computer_, in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy, check the DisplayLinkUserAgent.app

Comment: Even more there's an issue with High Sierra starting from 10.13.4 : https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/33252664-macos-high-sierra-10-13-4-and-mojave-10-14-early, we cannot have two external monitors even with the DisplayLink driver _Airplay_ workaround.